# WebRTC switch camera

Tags: javascript, camera, webrtc

I am currently working for WebRTC multipeer connection. I want to implement feature to switch camera from front to back while on call.
This is the code I am using to switch cameras

```
async function changevideo() {
   
   const audioSource = audioInputSelect.value;
   const videoSource = videoSelect.options[videoSelect.selectedIndex].value;
   var tempconstraints ={
       video: {
           deviceId: videoSource ? { exact: videoSource } : undefined,
           width: { max: 320 },
           height: { max: 240 }
       },
       audio: { deviceId: audioSource ? { exact: audioSource } : undefined },
   };
   var newstream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(tempconstraints);
  
   if (connections[socketId]) {
       Promise.all(connections[socketId].getSenders().map(function (sender) {
           debugger;
           return sender.replaceTrack(newstream.getTracks().find(function (track) {
               debugger;
               return track.kind === sender.track.kind;
           })).then(data =>
           {
               console.log(data);
           });;
       }));

       var track = localStream.getTracks().find(function (track) { return track.kind == videoTrack.kind });
       localStream.removeTrack(track);
       localStream.addTrack(videoTrack);

       connections[tempsocketid].onnegotiationneeded = function () {
           connections[tempsocketid].createOffer().then(function (offer) {
               return connections[tempsocketid].setLocalDescription(offer);
           }).then(function () {
               socket.emit('signal', socketId, JSON.stringify({ 'sdp': connections[tempsocketid].localDescription, 'room': roomNumber }), roomNumber);
           }).catch(e => console.log(e));
       }
   }
}
```

Here *connections* contains the RTCpeerconnection details of all type of connections connected.

`socketId` is the id of main user on which I want to switch camera. So, `connections[socketId]` gives me the RTCPeerConnection details of user with socketId.

`newstream` is the stream after switching camera.

If I directly update src of video to newstream then my camera changes only on my device.

I have searched alot but everywhere I am getting solution to use `replaceTrack` but it is not wokring in my case. Everytime I use it nothing happens on screen and I am also not getting any error in console.

**Update**

I have used the `onnegotiationneeded` with remove and add track.

`tempsocketid` is the socketId of another user who is connected.
So I have 2 users one have socketid stored in `socketId` and another having socketid stored in `tempsocketid`. So currently I am trying to switch camera of user with socketid `socketId`
and when negotiation is called then I am getting error in another users console.

`DOMException: Failed to execute 'addIceCandidate' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Error processing ICE candidate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue the problem was with socketId I was sending socketId of current user with different user.

As replace track was not working so I have used `removeTrack` and `addTrack` to force negotiation.

Here is my working code

```
if (connections[socketId]) {
    localStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = false;
    var track = localStream.getTracks().find(function (track) { return track.kind == videoTrack.kind });
    localStream.removeTrack(track);
    localStream.addTrack(videoTrack);

    connections[tempsocketid].onnegotiationneeded = function () {
        console.log('negotiationstarted');
        connections[tempsocketid].createOffer().then(function (offer) {
            return connections[tempsocketid].setLocalDescription(offer);
        }).then(function () {
            console.log('negotiation signal sent');
            socket.emit('signal', tempsocketid, JSON.stringify({ 'sdp': connections[tempsocketid].localDescription, 'room': roomNumber }), roomNumber);
        }).catch(e => console.log(e));
    }
    localStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably being unable to cause a renegotiaton so change to the `facingMode` of your camera cannot affect the other peers, but you do not use this explicitely as I see but `replaceTracks`. But still you may not being able to trigger a renegotiation. Checkout things that cause renegotiation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCRtpSender/replaceTrack#Usage_notes

Changing `facingMode` setting by applying constraints with `applyConstraints` may be a solution without using `replaceTracks`.

A strange idea coming to my mind to dispatch `negotiationneeded` event yourself, but I would try this after chasing the reason not being able to casue renegotiation itself by replacing track, or changing camera, and everything else.

About another reason: As for the reasons that casues renegotiation, your back camera resolution is most probably higher than the front camera, so it looks like a reason. If you start from the back camera first and then switch to front it might have been a no reason. I am suspicious about your `max` constraints of `width` nad `height`. They might be very lower for the both camera hence resulting in the same size, resoltion and so a no reason according to the list in the linked page above. I suggest removing them.

Also the `replaceTracks` returns a promise but the map function it is called from does not return anything, hence `undefined`. You are supposed to use the promises inside the array argument to `Promise.all`. I would suggest `return` those *promises* inside the `map` function.

Comment: I even tried with removing the height and width and even tested with the back camera first then front camera but the problem still exists

Comment: What about returnig a pomise instead undefined from mapping function calling replaceTracks inside?

Comment: I have updated the code. It is returning me undefined in console. I am new to this so please correct if I am using it in the wrong way.

Comment: Thanks, but output is still same.

Comment: I would suggest making sure you find a track form isnide of your newStream really. Also put the ten with cosole.log after Promise.all, I mean chained to it instead.

Comment: Waitt. It might be that your replace may be a cause to a renegotiation actuall, as I have thought the opposite previously. So it is not allowed, according to here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCRtpSender/replaceTrack
Please check the Return Value section, Exceptions section as well.

Comment: If your moidifcaiton would require a renegotiation it will not be allowed according to the above linked documentation. It will cause a `InvalidModificationError`.
Can you use a `catch` block to see the error type?

Comment: Instead of a track replacement that will cause a renegotitaton, which yours probably causing, can you use applyConstraints to apply a `facingMode` constraint to the video track. It is a constraint of video tarcks: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackConstraints

Comment: A renegotiation might be really unnecessary, that might be why of the system does not let such track modifications, since not probably much changes for the user's session with a camera change, like codecs change etc. But still at the end there are `addTracks` and `removeTracks` methods of the rtc peer connection that would definitly trigger `negotionneeded` event. I do not suggest these to use unless you find a better solution. Some of the suggestions of mine above works I hope.

Comment: @Ravi ay progress?

Comment: I have already tried `applyConstraints` but it also not wokring and even in catch block I am not getting anything and same for `addTracks` and `removeTracks`

Comment: I wonder why. I hope you find the solution and if you do I would like to know it. Can you update here with an answer to your question?

Comment: Yes ofcourse. @sçuçu Can you please confirm about `onnegotiationneeded` as I think I have not used it properly. I have updated the code with negotiation.